# How to rename wp-includes folder?

Tags: include

Is there a way that we could rename wp-includes folder

I have found out there are ways to do for other folders. But how do we do it for wp-includes folder?
http://pythoughts.com/how-to-hide-that-you-use-wordpress/

Comment: If you're looking to mask the fact that you use WordPress, have a look at this: http://kovshenin.com/2013/dont-hide-the-fact-that-youre-using-wordpress/

Comment: Even you could do that: the first enqueued core JavaScript would tell the new name to everyone. This is really pointless.

Comment: I agree with toscho. There are twenty different ways I can think of off the top of head to tell that a site is running WordPress, and I can identify many other CMS's too. A malicious script could run all those checks and more in less than a second. Hiding that you use WordPress is not worth the work and I doubt it affords much security.

Comment: It affords decent security through obfuscation if you address all 20 ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately not at the moment. If you look in `wp-includes/default_constants.php`, the `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and other constants all have a `if ( ! defined(constant) )` check before them.

`WPINC` (the `wp-includes` constant) does not. It's defined in `wp-settings.php`, and has no `if ( ! defined(WPINC) )` check, so defining it before hand (in your `wp-config.php`) would just result in an error.

Also, altering core you could do this, but as soon as you update WordPress, Core files would be reverted, and therefore it would revert back to `wp-includes`.

I suggestion just masking your site with WordPress in a subdirectory (call it `xadw` or something nobody would guess) and just set the home URL to be the actual domain. Then put your `wp-content` folder in another folder, so it won't be obviously when people look at uploads, etc.